# Can not add android plugin to netbeans 8.0.2 (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, netbeans-8

i am trying to make an android app in net beans 8.0.2 in Java language. i can not add nbandroid plugin to netbeans. i searched on google. but all of they say i should add plugin from "nbandroid.org". but that website ifs no longer available. If you know another way to make android app in netbeans please help me! I am sorry if i asked unnecessary question. and thank you for your answers!!!

Comment: Why are you not using Android Studio ?

Comment: android studio is not working properly in my system

Comment: Please update your system then. I don't think there is plugin exist that support Net-beans or Eclipse now days

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a successor of the discontinued nbandroid-plugin in development: https://github.com/NBANDROIDTEAM/NBANDROID-V2